# Python - end a function from another function

Tags: python

Is it possible to stop bar through foo, but not affect bar1? I know we could return a flag from foo, and use then "return" bar through judging the flag foo returned, but I am wondering if there is a more neat way to do it.

```
def foo():
    ...

def bar():
    foo()
    ...

def bar1():
    ...
```

Comment: You can raise an exception but this isn't cleaner

Comment: You could potentially do something like this by raising an exception from `foo()`, but this would require some exception handling either within `bar()` or higher up the stack.  You are probably better off just returning from `bar()` based on the return code from `foo()`.

Comment: What concrete problem are you trying to solve with this behavior?  Describe the problem and we can respond with pythonic solutions.

Comment: I don't understand the connection with `bar1()`. Does `bar1` also call `foo`?(and if yes, why didn't you write it in your example?). Anyway one way is to use `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` to check if the function was called by `bar`, and then call `sys.exit()`. This stops the execution of `bar` but not `bar1` when `foo` is called(it has the small side effect of shutting down the whole interpreter, but you didn't clarify what you wanted to achieve).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You'll need to end `bar` by using the return value of `foo`.